# Protractor unable to compare variable to web element due to promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

My plan for this test was to store the inner text of an element, make a change then check the element against the variable and confirm that it had changed

```
var fixedValue= element(by.xpath('/html/body/section/div/section/section[2]/div[1]/ul/li[4]/a/span[2]')).getText();
            var totalValue = element(by.xpath('/html/body/section/div/section/section[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a/span[2]')).getText();
            var progressValue = element(by.xpath('/html/body/section/div/section/section[2]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a/span[2]')).getText();
```

make a change then expect

```
expect(element(by.xpath('/html/body/section/div/section/section[2]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a/span[2]')).getText()).toEqual(progressValue);
```

However in my console I get the failed assertion

```
Expected '17' to equal NaN
```

It seems like this is because the promise of the first variable hasn't been fulfilled so there is nothing to compare too.

So my question is how can I get the expect to check the first variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ideas behind protractor is to make things like this easier. For example, you could find the text using `by.binding()` or `by.model()`. These do the work of waiting for promises/server request/etc. to be completed.

Take a look at this [tutorial page](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md), in particular what they describe in step 1.

If you've tried this and it didn't work, or it doesn't quite address your situation, you might want to edit your question and provide more details. In general, try to avoid writing tests as you've shown above, they tend to be brittle (test breaks when you refactor your view). I've found using [page objects](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md) to be very helpful.